# Where are generic types stored in java class files?

Tags: java, generics, jvm

I am well aware that generic types are erased from Java code when it is compiled.  What information (attributes?) do 1.5+ JVMs use to implement `getGenericType` , etc. ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They are stored in `Signature` attributes; see section 4.8.8 of the [updated Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/jvms-clarify.html), as well as section 4.4.4 for the format of the field type signature.

Here's an example using `javap -verbose java.util.Map`:

```
public interface java.util.Map
  SourceFile: "Map.java"
  Signature: length = 0x2
   00 1E 
  [other attributes omitted]
```

The `Signature` attribute here specifies (if you read this as big-endian, like all integer quantities in the JVM class file format are) constant pool value #30 (30 = 0x1E). So let's have a look there:

```
const #30 = Asciz       <K:Ljava/lang/Object;V:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;;
```

Read this in the context of the grammar specified in 4.4.4. So, this uses two type parameters, `K extends java.lang.Object` and `V extends java.lang.Object`. The type itself (`Map`) also extends class `java.lang.Object`, and no interfaces.

Answer (score 21):

Java generics are indeed implemented by [type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so there is no type information in the bytecode.

For example, let's take a look two classes which declare a `List` field, one in generic and the other in non-generic form:

```
class NonGeneric {
    List list;
}
```

And,

```
class Generic {
    List<String> list;
}
```

In both cases, the resulting bytecode is the following:

```
  Code:
   Stack=3, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   new #2; //class java/util/ArrayList
   8:   dup
   9:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
   12:  putfield    #4; //Field list:Ljava/util/List;
   15:  return
```

There is no reference to the `String` type used in the `ArrayList` nor `List`. So, we can see that generics is indeed implemented by type erasure.

However, if we look at the constant pool, we can find a difference.

The non-generic constant pool:

```
  Constant pool:
const #1 = Method   #6.#15; //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
const #2 = class    #16;    //  java/util/ArrayList
const #3 = Method   #2.#15; //  java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
const #4 = Field    #5.#17; //  NonGeneric.list:Ljava/util/List;
const #5 = class    #18;    //  NonGeneric
const #6 = class    #19;    //  java/lang/Object
const #7 = Asciz    list;
const #8 = Asciz    Ljava/util/List;;
const #9 = Asciz    <init>;
const #10 = Asciz   ()V;
// snip the rest //
```

The generic constant pool:

```
  Constant pool:
const #1 = Method   #6.#17; //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
const #2 = class    #18;    //  java/util/ArrayList
const #3 = Method   #2.#17; //  java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
const #4 = Field    #5.#19; //  Generic.list:Ljava/util/List;
const #5 = class    #20;    //  Generic
const #6 = class    #21;    //  java/lang/Object
const #7 = Asciz    list;
const #8 = Asciz    Ljava/util/List;;
const #9 = Asciz    Signature;
const #10 = Asciz   Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/String;>;;
const #11 = Asciz   <init>;
const #12 = Asciz   ()V;
// snip the rest//
```

As can be seen, in the `Generic` class, we can see there are two extra constants, `#9` and `#10`, in the constant pool, which mentions that the `List` has the generic type of `String`.

(And incorporating new knowledge that I learned from [Chris Jester-Young's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937933/where-are-generic-types-stored-in-java-class-files/937999#937999))

Looking further at the disassembly of the class file, there is a reference to the constant #10 right before the `Code: block` of the `Generic` class:

```
java.util.List list;
  Signature: length = 0x2
   00 0A
```

The hexadecimal value `0A` is `10` in decimal, which refers to the constant pool `#10`:

```
const #10 = Asciz   Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/String;>;;
```

Therefore, the information from the constant pool is used in order to indicate that a field is of a generic type.