# How can Spring get generic type information during runtime regarding "Strongly-typed collection"?

Tags: java, spring, generics, type-erasure

I read below in Spring 3.0 document:

*Strongly-typed collection (Java 5+ only)*

*In Java 5 and later, you can use strongly typed collections (using generic types). That is, it is possible to declare a Collection type such that it can only contain String elements (for example). If you are using Spring to dependency-inject a strongly-typed Collection into a bean, you can take advantage of Spring's type-conversion support such that the elements of your strongly-typed Collection instances are converted to the appropriate type prior to being added to the Collection.*

```
public class Foo {

  private Map<String, Float> accounts;

  public void setAccounts(Map<String, Float> accounts) {
      this.accounts = accounts;
  }
}

<beans>
  <bean id="foo" class="x.y.Foo">
      <property name="accounts">
          <map>
              <entry key="one" value="9.99"/>
              <entry key="two" value="2.75"/>
              <entry key="six" value="3.99"/>
          </map>
      </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

***When the accounts property of the foo bean is prepared for injection, the generics information about the element type of the strongly-typed Map is available by reflection.** Thus Spring's type conversion infrastructure recognizes the various value elements as being of type Float, and the string values 9.99, 2.75, and 3.99 are converted into an actual Float type.*

how can this be possible? As I know generic type information is erased during compilation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works because types are erased for objects, but not for fields. Have a look at [Where are generic types stored in java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937933) for a detailed explanation how it works.

In essence, there is a [`Field.getGenericType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType()) method introduced in (surprise) 1.5 that always returns reliable generic type of a field. So Spring *is* capable of reading `accounts` generic types (`<String, Float>`) via plain reflection.

Note that the same mechanism is used e.g. in [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa). This is completely valid and working:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Order> orders;

}

@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

}
```

Without this Java 5 feature the JPA provider would not be able to figure out what is the second side of the `orders` *one-to-many* relationship.