# Java Generics type erasure casting

Tags: java

How does the java compiler know to provide appropriate cast to the objects in a generic collection when the type information isn't available at runtime due to erasure?

Comment: Casts only happen at compile time.

Comment: Casts are _generated_ by the compiler at compile time. They _happen_ at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you call e.g. `list.get(foo)`, and the list is an `ArrayList<String>`, then the result of `get` is casted to a `String` by the *caller*, not the callee.  The caller knows at compile time what the result should be cast to (a `String`), so the cast can be inserted there.

Answer (score 0):

As per oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

- Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
- Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
- Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.

So, your class file contains either bounded class (or) Object instead of generic type.

Comment: But List<String> list = new ArrayList<String> this will be replaced by List list = new ArrayList(); so how does the compiler know while retrieving an object from the list that the object type needs to be cast into string ?

Comment: see this thread that may clear your confusion. At byte code level .class file stores some generic information which can be manipulated using relections. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937933/where-are-generic-types-stored-in-java-class-files