# Working of generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to see the working of Generics and it says that classes are compiled to normal classes and there is no type mentioned anywhere  and there is checkcast operator which is passed the type to which the Object class is cast to which we are getting from ArrayList.

```
String i=ArrayListObject.get(position);
```

But when there are no types how come the compiler know that a generic ArrayList can only store the type declared in <>. Where is this information stored while compiling the class.
kindly update

Comment: It's called type erasure.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html.  Java generics are not done like C++ generics, where an entirely unique class is created for each type.

Comment: @duffymo He knows about type erasure. He asks how the compiler can do its job when all type information is erased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only half of the truth.

Yes, at **runtime**, none of that type information is used; just "Objects" are moved around. That is what is called **type erasure**.

But: the information which fields, methods, ... were defined using some generic T is very well compiled into the class file. So that a compiler can read that class file; and can understand that you want to instantiate some `ArrayList<String>` for example.

In other words: you are talking about **two** different things here: A) a compiler reading the class file so it can do its job and B) a JVM reading class files to **run** code.

So, when you are really curious **where** exactly that information is stored, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937933/where-are-generic-types-stored-in-java-class-files)!

Comment: Thanks. the information was indeed helpful.the link had the complete details.