# How Parameterized types Objects are stored in memory and how the type information is retained?

Tags: java, generics

```
class Gen3<T extends Number>
{
    T val;
    Gen3(T ob)
    {

    val=ob;    
    }
    T getOb()
    {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Case 1:

```
Gen<Integer> a=new Gen<Integer>(2);
String b=a.getOb();//compile error
```

As we know at runtime above expression would look like:

```
Gen a=new Gen(2);
```

So how method getOb() would remember that it has to return Integer. Does that information gets stored in the class object?

Comment: This question already has an answer here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937933/where-are-generic-types-stored-in-java-class-files

Comment: sorry that is not my only question

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, `a` doesn't know that it has to return an `Integer`. It returns an `Integer` because the object that was stored in `val` is an `Integer`, and that object is what `getOb` returns.

Comment: So what T is replaced with? Is it replaced with Integer or Object?

and where this information is stored by the compiler?

Comment: @RishabShinghal In this case, it's [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) to `Number`.

Comment: so you mean to say class Definition at Runtime would be,

class Gen3
{
    Number val;
    Gen3(Number ob)
    {

    val=ob;    
    }
    Number getOb()
    {
        return val;
    }
} 

So is it right?

Comment: That is correct. It is also what it says in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How Parameterized types Objects are stored in memory

Same way as any other object.

> and how the type information is retained?

It isn't retained in the class. Your class is compiled as though `T` was `Number`, but the object code that *uses* any specific instance is generated to use whatever `T` is for that instance.

Comment: So you meant to say that for compiler T can be anything that extends Number. That I understood.

Suppose if parameterized type object got created with T as Integer, so information about T being Integer would be stored at object level?

If its correct then how that information is stored in an object?

Comment: @RishabShinghal Don't tell me what I meant to say. `T extends Number` is right there in your source code, not in my answer. You didn't need to understand it from me: you *wrote* it. I've already answered all this stuff.

Comment: I just want to know that how the type information is stored at object level?

Comment: What part of (a) 'same as any other object', (b) 'it isn't retained in the class', and (c) the object code that *uses* it is generated ...' didn't you understand? Have you even read this answer? It certainly doesn't seem like it. All you've done is impute to me things I didn't say, and completely ignore what I did say.