# Reason for ambiguous error in java generics code while trying to overload/override

Tags: java, generics

While going through generics, I am not able to understand why the error is coming:

```
class Box <T> {
    private T theThing;
    public Box( T t)        { theThing = t; }
    public void reset( T t) { theThing = t; }
}
class WordBox< S extends CharSequence > extends Box< String > {
    public WordBox( S t)    { super(t.toString().toLowerCase()); }
    public void reset( S t) {
     //   super.reset(t.toString().toLowerCase());
    }

}
public class ss {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordBox<String> city = new WordBox<String>("Skogland");
       city.reset("Stavanger"); // error: ambiguous**
    }
}
```

I can understand, method worldbox.reset () is not overriding the method from BOX, instead it is overloading.
After type erasure, I am assuming this will be code :

```
class Box  {
    private Object theThing;
    public Box( Object t)        { theThing = t; }
    public void reset( Object t) { theThing = t; }
}
class WordBox extends Box{
    public WordBox( CharSequence t)    { super(t.toString().toLowerCase()); }
    public void reset( CharSequence t) {
        super.reset(t.toString().toLowerCase());
    }

}
public class ss {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordBox<String> city = new WordBox<String>("Skogland");
       city.reset("Stavanger"); 
    }
}
```

So, city.reset("Stavanger") should call the method from Worldbox.reset , as String extends charsequence and it seems to be closest match.

Could anyone please explain why the ambiguous error is coming in this code?

Comment: You should not consider the type-erased version of your code, because type-erasure happens at runtime, whereas overload resolution happens at compile-time. When the compiler is figuring out which overload to use, it is fully aware of the generic type information. Do you agree that, if we consider the non-type-erased version of your code, your code is ambiguous?

Comment: @Sweeper , As per my knowledge, type erasure happens at compile time not at time . When compiler generates .class file, it has all generics information erased.thats why i was getting confused in above piece of code?

Comment: [Well, not exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937933/where-are-generic-types-stored-in-java-class-files). Class files contain generic information. I do admit that what I said was a bit inaccurate. It is useful to think that type-erasure happens _after_ compile time (it actually happens, as you said, at code generation), because I repeat, the compiler knows all about generics, and it will use this information to resolve overloads.

Comment: This could clear your doubts : https://hajsoftutorial.com/java-ambiguity-errors-generics/

Comment: Thanks @Amitkumar. I still could nto understand the last part in above article. If i look at type erased code , then new Gen<integer,Integer>.set(4) should be matching with Gen(Integer> , not with Gen<Object>